# Redux-form field with input component re-renders on first character causing the keyboard to collapse

Tags: redux-form

I have a form which is made using some logic, loading components from an external API. 
This was working great using redux-form 6.3.2 and react 16.0.0-alpha.12.
The app is built with expo and I had to update expo SDK to the latest, which updates react to 16.3.1 and forced me to update redux-form. Since I had to update I went to the latest version (7.3.0) which led to some issues in the app that I was able to fix, but for this one I can't find a solution:
The forms is created using fieldArray and Field, so the createElement, after some processing does this:

```
return fieldObj.fields ?

  (<View key={idx} style={style}>
    <FieldArray {...fieldObj}
     key={idx}
     name={fieldObj.name}
     component={component} />
  </View>)
:
  (<Field {...fieldObj}
           key={idx}
           style={style}
           type={fieldObj.type}
           name={fieldObj.name}
           component={component} />);
```

And we get component using a formWrapperHOC:

```
formLib.FormWrapperHOC(formElement, {
      onChangeCB,
      onBlurCB,
      stylesKeys,
      formName,
      extraProps,
    })
```

which in turn does some things until it renders:

```
//FormWrapperHOC render method:
    render() { return (<WrappedComponent {...this._massageProps()} />); }
```

So when I insert the first character in this input I see the events:

```
@@redux-form/FOCUS
@@redux-form/CHANGE
@@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS
@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD
@@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD
```

I tried removing validations, so UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS is not called, but item still rerenders.

Another thing that caught my eye is that the field is registered and later unregistered.

I end up with the input field and the character I entered, but keyboard is collapsed. If I focus on the field again everything works as expected: No call to UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS because the field already has some content on, only CHANGE is triggered.

Since this works fine with redux-form 6.3.2, I'm pretty sure I need to make a change in my code for it to work with redux-form 7.3.0. Thing is, I was not able to find where is the issue, so any help or lead for where to look will be greatly appreciated.